# How to make a x = y or z statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement

In my program, I have a String called yesOrNo that is a keyboard input. I created an if statement to test if yesOrNo is one of the following : "Y", "y", "Yes", 
"yes" by using the || operator.

I got the error message: The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String. What is the right way to do something like this? Thanks.

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yesOrNo = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println(yesOrNo + "?" );

    if (yesOrNo.equals("Y" || "y" || "Yes || "yes")){
```

Answer (score 8):

The shortest I can think of is :

```
if (yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") || yesOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
```

Comment: Ah! I was wondering if you could do something that could ignore capitals. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Your syntax is invalid. It needs to have separate clauses:

```
if(yesOrNo.equals("Y") || yesOrNo.equals("y")...)
```

or cleaner would be if you used regex:

```
if(yesOrNo.matches("Y|y|Yes|yes")) { 
    // Code.
}
```

**Extra Reading**

- You should look at the [String Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). They detail all sorts of useful stuff.
- Read up on [Regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). It makes complex `String` comparison very simple.
- Finally, look at the different [Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to see what kind of logical statements you can form, with the correct syntax.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into these links.

Answer (score 3):

Two ways:

1. Using `equals`:

   ```
   if (yesOrNo.equals("Y") ||
       yesOrNo.equals("y") ||
       yesOrNo.equals("Yes") ||
       yesOrNo.equals("yes")) {
       //...
   }
   ```
2. Using regexp (shorther than using || multiple times):

   ```
   if (yesOrNo.toLowerCase().matches("y|yes")) {
       //...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could create a list of acceptable answers and check whether the answer is in that list.

```
List<String> kindOfYes = Arrays.asList("yes", "y", "okay", "righto");
if (kindOfYes.contains(yesOrNo.toLowerCase())) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if(yesOrNo.equals("Y") || yesOrNo.equals("y") 
   || yesOrNo.equals("Yes") || yesOrNo.equals("yes"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
if (yesOrNo.equals("Y") || yesOrNo.equals("y") || yesOrNo.equals("Yes") || yesOrNo.equals("yes")){
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (yesOrNo.equals("Y") || yesOrNo.equals("y") || yesOrNo.equals("Yes")  || yesOrNo.equals("yes"))
```

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of how this works rather than just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

What about the next code?

```
String yesOrNo = keyboard.nextLine();
if (yesOrNo.toLowerCase().charAt(0) == 'y') {
    //  
}
```

<sub>**NOTE**: Do you think there's a **quicker** way? I think not.</sub>

Comment: Hey @LuiggiMendoza  Do you really think that the user write something like that? By the way, greetings to Peru.

Comment: I expect anything from users, see [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=programmers+users&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=ck_-U9XpN4-4ggTgsoHoAg&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1517&bih=714&dpr=0.9). Thanks for the greetings :), hello to Mexican people.

Answer (score 0):

Your program **syntax** is wrong.

This is correct:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yesOrNo = keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println(yesOrNo + "?" );

    if(yesOrNo.equals("Y") || yesOrNo.equals("y") || yesOrNo.equals("Yes") || yesOrNo.equals("yes")) {
```